# Inconsistent Enum Casting Results in C#

Tags: c#, casting, enums

I was recently revisiting some of the strange behavior of C# related to casting an integer into an existing enum where some enum integer values are assigned explicitly and some are assigned in order. Using LinqPad 4, I built the following enum:

```
public enum Hurf {
    Foo,
    Bar,
    Derp,
    Duh = 2,
    Lerp,
    Mur,
    Dur = 3
}
```

Using the following Main block body in C# Program mode, I perform the following casts:

```
Console.WriteLine((Hurf)2);
Console.WriteLine((int)Hurf.Derp);

Console.WriteLine((Hurf)3);
Console.WriteLine((int)Hurf.Lerp);
```

This results in the following output:

```
Derp
2
Dur
3
```

Strange, it appeared that in the first cast, since there were two items with the integer value of 2, that it defaulted to the first one, which was "Derp". With the same logic, I perform another cast using integer value 3, and this time it results in the SECOND value of 3, which is "Dur".

I decide to add another item to the bottom of the enum directly below "Dur" as "Test" and set it to 0.

```
public enum Hurf {
    Foo,
    Bar,
    Derp,
    Duh = 2,
    Lerp,
    Mur,
    Dur = 3,
    Test = 0
}
```

This doesn't change the behavior of the first cast, but now the result for the second cast is "Lerp", which would be consistent with it casting to the first value of 3 that was set in the enumeration.

```
Duh
2
Lerp
3
```

For obvious reasons, I wouldn't rely on this type of casting to begin with, but it would be nice to know why this behavior exists and is affected by an arbitrary manual assignment at the bottom of the enum list. (Also, setting "Test" to a value above 3 causes the original behavior to return.)

Answer (score 8):

It's not the casting that's the problem - it's the conversion to a string representation. `Lerp` and `Dur` are the same value - you can't distinguish between them.

Indeed, if you call `ToString()` directly on them, like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(Hurf.Lerp.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(Hurf.Dur.ToString());
```

... you should expect to see the same output twice. It just isn't well-defined *which* output you'll get.

The [documentation for `Enum.ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/16c1xs4z(v=vs.110).aspx) explicitly states:

> If multiple enumeration members have the same underlying value and you attempt to retrieve the string representation of an enumeration member's name based on its underlying value, your code should not make any assumptions about which name the method will return.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So what you're saying is that a cast from an integer to the enumeration type is doing a ToString which produces wonky behavior. I still find it interesting that arbitrary changes to other members cause the order to change for determining which item is selected for the conversion (sometimes first sometimes second).

Comment: @IanJ.: No, not at all. *You're* (implicitly) calling `ToString()` by calling `Console.WriteLine` and passing in a value of the enum type. The casting has no "wonky" behaviour at all - the cast is simply producing a `Hurf` value with the same underlying value as the original integer.

Comment: I think we're still sort of focusing on the wrong thing here, which is why that ToString is so inconsistent.

Comment: @IanJ: It's inconsistent because there's no "right" answer in the ambiguous case, and it's an implementation detail - like the order in which a dictionary's members are iterated. What *is* important is that you differentiate between the enum/int conversion and the enum/string conversion.